# NVIDIA GT220 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hdmi

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu all together. Installed it on my first PC build last night and I'm  having trouble getting the drivers set.

I currently have the card in the board and I have Nvidia 319 drivers active. I installed Sysinfo guessing that would help me get the card up an running and when I click the Nvidia tab, all the details of the card are unknown.

I clicked on display settings and I get a error message about Nvidia driver x. installed NVCLOCK but cant open the app due to the lack of appropriate drivers. I just wanna get the card working so i can use the HDMI port.

I currently have no speakers, so no sound. can anyone direct me to a forum or guide me to getting the card working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in 13.10. However, I was having problems with the black screen after a login session. The first answer helped me out.

[Ubuntu 13.10 - Black screen after logging in after installing nVidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375841/ubuntu-13-10-black-screen-after-logging-in-after-installing-nvidia-drivers)